# GWT / Java - somewhat basic UI question on sample code

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I was looking through the sample gwt code provided with gwt, and in hacking around with it - i had two questions re. things that we'nt particularly clear to me (code posted below - slightly long: sorry)

1) The popup dialog box doesnt seem to be set to be 'hidden' at first, and even though its been assembled, it doesnt actually show up until the button is clicked - why is this? (i dont, for example see any dialogBox.Hide() call

2) in creating a similar dialogbox, basically through copying the code, i'm facing the problem that between calls to the dialogbox - the contents persist, so if i hide the box with the button on the dialog box, the next time it is called - the new contents are just appended above it... what am i doing wrong?

many thanks!

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
        nameField.setText("GWT User");
        final Label errorLabel = new Label();

        // We can add style names to widgets
        sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

        // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
        // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
        RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
        RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
        RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);

        // Focus the cursor on the name field when the app loads
        nameField.setFocus(true);
        nameField.selectAll();

        // Create the popup dialog box
        final DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
        dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
        dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        final Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        // We can set the id of a widget by accessing its Element
        closeButton.getElement().setId("closeButton");
        final Label textToServerLabel = new Label();
        final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
        VerticalPanel dialogVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        dialogVPanel.addStyleName("dialogVPanel");
        dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<b>Sending name to the server:</b>"));
        dialogVPanel.add(textToServerLabel);
        dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<br><b>Server replies:</b>"));
        dialogVPanel.add(serverResponseLabel);
        dialogVPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        dialogVPanel.add(closeButton);
        dialogBox.setWidget(dialogVPanel);

        // Add a handler to close the DialogBox
        closeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                dialogBox.hide();
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                sendButton.setFocus(true);
            }
        });

        // Create a handler for the sendButton and nameField
        class MyHandler implements ClickHandler, KeyUpHandler {
            /**
             * Fired when the user clicks on the sendButton.
             */
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                sendNameToServer();
            }

            /**
             * Fired when the user types in the nameField.
             */
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                    sendNameToServer();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Send the name from the nameField to the server and wait for a response.
             */
            private void sendNameToServer() {
                // First, we validate the input.
                errorLabel.setText("");
                String textToServer = nameField.getText();
                if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(textToServer)) {
                    errorLabel.setText("Please enter at least four characters");
                    return;
                }

                // Then, we send the input to the server.
                sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                textToServerLabel.setText(textToServer);
                serverResponseLabel.setText("");
                greetingService.greetServer(textToServer,
                        new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                                dialogBox
                                        .setText("Remote Procedure Call - Failure");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .addStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(SERVER_ERROR);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }

                            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                                dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .removeStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(result);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        // Add a handler to send the name to the server
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        sendButton.addClickHandler(handler);
        nameField.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DialogBox is not shown by default - you have to explicitly show it via `show()` or `center()`.

About the second part - is the source code you provided the one causing the problem? It doesn't seem so from a quick glance. The problem you described seem like it might be caused by trying to add content to the `dialogVPanel` (that's holding the content of the `DialogBox`) without first `clear()`ing it.